# How to compare two dates in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there a specific way of comparing two dates in Jinja?

I have googled and searched but have found close to nothing related to this specific question.

The closest thing I have found is this, from the official Jinja2 documentation:

```
It is also possible to sort by an attribute (for example to sort by the date of an object) by specifying the attribute parameter:

{% for item in iterable|sort(attribute='date') %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should be able to compare them as you would in python in a `set`, `if` blocks

Comment: Are you trying to sort a list or create an if statement?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you are looking for but this is how you can compare a datetime to datetime.now().

I have found that a datetime object can create a new datetime object:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: wasNow = datetime.datetime.now()

In [3]: wasNow
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 17, 21, 889530)

In [4]: wasNow.now()
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 17, 30, 105077)
```

and now that you have a date object in the jinja template you are able to create a new datetime object from an existing one and compare it like:

```
{% if item.date < item.date.now() %}
  <p> This will display if the item.date is before item.date.now(). </p>
{% endif %}
```

I hope that this helps you some in trying to compare dates using jinja.

Answer (score -2):

I also had this problem and solved it a different way. Instead of using dates, you may be able to get away with using the item IDs.

```
{% if item.id < 561095 %}
   DO ONE THING
{% else %}
   DO SOMETHING ELSE
{% endif %}
```